# Program for exporting data to CSV files

Tags: windows, database, csv, product-management, woocommerce

I'm setting up a WooCommerce store, and I'm after an application for Windows that will allow me to put together products and then export to a CSV file for upload into WooCommerce.  I'm thinking the application wouldn't specifically be a product manager, but rather something that will allow me to define a record type, and then create many of them and export to CSV.

It'd need the ability to add text fields, selects and images (with filenames being exported), and an export option and that's pretty much it!

I'm envisioning the program could save its data either as a csv file or in e.g. a sqlite database.

Comment: CSV is text-only, so there are no specific data types. From what you describe, any calculation software (such as Excel or LibreOffice Calc) can do that, both can export to CSV.

Comment: @Izzy Spreadsheets are notoriously bad at this because they don't allow editing long descriptions easily.

Comment: OK, there we've got the first item missing from your requirements list :) Any more? May I recommend taking a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Afterwards you might wish to [edit] your question to improve your chances of well matching answers ;) Good luck!

Comment: I'd thought editing the text field would have been pretty obvious from the description?

Comment: I'm not familiar with shopping/commerce apps, so to me it looked like "field definitions" (think of HTML code). So I was just pointing to possible improvements but won't argue if you say it's "obvious enough". No my specific area of expertise ;)